Rank of Hadamard product of column-wise polynomial evaluations and row-wise exponential evaluations
Consider the Hadamard product $A \odot B$ between two special matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. The columns of $A$ are evaluations of polynomials, while the rows of $B$ are evaluations of exponentials (details below).
$\bullet$ Matrix $A$ is obtained like so:
Take $m$ non-zero polynomials $f_1(x),\dots,f_m(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $d$. Evaluate each polynomial $f_j(x)$ on $n$ distinct points $x_1,\dots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the $j$-th column of $A$ is the multi-evaluation vector $[f_j(x_1),\dots,f_j(x_n)]^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$.
$\bullet$ Matrix $B$ is obtained like so:
Take $n$ exponentials $g_1(y) = \exp(c_1 y), \dots, g_n(y) = \exp(c_n y)$ with distinct $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Evaluate each exponential $g_i(y)$ on $m$ distinct points $y_1,\dots,y_m \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the $i$-th row of $B$ is the multi-evaluation vector $[g_i(y_1), \dots, g_i(y_m)] \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times m}$.
I am looking for a lower bound on the rank of the Hadamard product $A \odot B$ depending on the degree bound $d$ of the polynomials in $A$.
$\bullet$ This is what I know:
When $d=0$, i.e., when the polynomials are constant, then one can show that $A \odot B$ has full rank.
Consequently, it is not hard to see that for $d>0$, if $f_1(x) = \cdots = f_m(x)$, then the rank of $A \odot B$ drops by at most $d$. But does this hold also when the polynomials are not identical? If not, is it possible to give some other bound?
